# I want to calculate the timedifference between to times

Tags: r, types

I want to calculate the difference of two columns of a dataframe containing times. Since not always a value from the same column ist bigger/later, I have to do a workaround with an if-clause:

```
counter = 1

while(counter <= nrow(data)){

  if(data$time_end[counter] - data$time_begin[counter] < 0){

    data$chargingDuration[counter] = 1-abs(data$time_end[counter]-data$time_begin[counter])

  }

  if(data$time_end[counter] - data$time_begin[counter] > 0){

    data$chargingDuration[counter] = data$time_end[counter]-data$time_begin[counter]

  }

  counter = counter + 1

}
```

The output I get is a decimalvalue smaller than 1 (i.e.: 0,53322 meaning half a day)... However, if I use my console and calculate the timedifference manually for a single line, I get my desired result looking like 02:12:03...
Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: Without any data to reproduce your problem, we can't provide a meaningful answer.  A couple of suggestions, R is a vectorized language so `data$time_end - data$time_begin` will work on the entire column thus avoiding the need for a loop.  Also if your data is a proper date/time object then using the function `difftime` is a suggestion.

Comment: The problem is, that since the events occured on different dates, it might have started at 21:00:00 on a saturday and ended at 02:00:00 on a sunday. Using a simple vector difference would get me negative times. Negative times are immediately converted into a double value such as -0.443, whilst positive values would remain in the desired 03:23:12 format. Therefore I included a loop as a workaround.
Data would look the one I posted as an example in my answer...